# Pass listbox items from page1 to page2 using sessioon

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listbox

Can anyone show an example how listbox and session work.
E.g to pass listbox items from page1 to page2.
thx!

```
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                lstFarger.Items.Add(blo);
                lstFarger.Items.Add(gron);
                lstFarger.Items.Add(brun);
                lstFarger.Items.Add(gul);
            }
        }

        protected void btnLaggTill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!lstLagdaFarger.Items.Contains(lstFarger.SelectedItem) && lstLagdaFarger.Items.Count<3)
            {
                lstLagdaFarger.Items.Add(lstFarger.SelectedItem.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                lblFelMeddelande.Visible = true;
            }
            if (lstLagdaFarger.Items.Count == 3)
            {

                Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
            }
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass ListItems, you can save the datasource in session. However, is it really necessary to use the `Session`, why can't you  select the data again? You  gain not much but a `Session` needs server memory and also could contain outdated data.

Comment: Ok. Could u show me an example how to do that ? However I need just to pass data from listbox which is on page 1 to another listbox on page 2.

Comment: What _data_ do you use? Can you show some code? You just need to store it in session and then read it in page2. You can store anything in session.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: after i add  three items to listbox it takes me to WebForm2 and I want that listitems i added to appear in WebForm2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to pass `ListItems`, you can save the datasource in session. However, is it really necessary to use the `Session`, why can't you select the data again? You gain not much but a `Session` needs server memory and also could contain outdated data.

Having said that, if you really want to use the session to store the listitems...

In your button click handler:

```
if (lstLagdaFarger.Items.Count == 3)
{
    Session["LagdaFargerItems"] = lstLagdaFarger.Items;
    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
}
```

in page 2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && Session["LagdaFargerItems"] != null)
    { 
        ListItemCollection lic = (ListItemCollection)Session["LagdaFargerItems"];
        foreach(ListItem li in lic)
            lstLagdaFarger.Items.Add(li); // your other ListBox on page2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! Very kind of you!